# Python File System Bottleneck, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, file

So basically I have a folder that looks like this:

```
MyFolder\
          data_1.txt
          data_2.txt
          data_3.txt
          ...
          data_very_large_number.txt
```

I want to process each of the files. My plan was to run 10 instances of a script that each process 1/10th of the files.

So basically, I did the following:

```
 python script.py 1
 python script.py 2
 ...
 python script.py 10
```

But I'm noticing that only the first instance of `script.py` is actually processing anything at all. After the first instance is done processing the second instance starts to process. I am guessing that this is a File System bottleneck.

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this issue with Python?

Comment: Buy a faster hard disk? Compress the files? Or: **measure** to find the bottleneck rather than guessing?

Comment: so you created a shell script/bat file with "python script.py 1...." is that correct? In that case that's the problem

Comment: Are you running this from a Linux shell or something like this?

Comment: Did you put the scripts in the background (i.e. python script.py 1 &)? If not, your shell will just execute the commands sequentially.

Comment: Also Sergio, how is that the problem? I am very interested in figuring out why.

Comment: But you mean that you start the first one then just after it finishes you start the second one? Or this is a shell script?

Comment: I ran all of the scripts individually, each on a different core

Comment: I went on the commandline and ran them indivudally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to run these scripts in parallel, but if you want to keep starting them manually from the command line you should do it like this:

```
python script.py 1 &
python script.py 2 &
```

and so on.

Comment: But I ran the scripts from the commandline, they should already run in parallel right?

Comment: Yes. If they take up some time you can even check they're running with `ps aux | grep script.py`. If they process the file too fast they may end up before you start the next one though.

Comment: They all seem to be running.. however they still seem to process in a sequence. My goal was to really run them in parallel so that I could save a lot of time.

Comment: I don't think so. The Linux kernel will give a little time slice for each one, so they are really processing in parallel (specially if your processor is a multicore). It may seem they are finishing in sequence because you are starting them sequentially and, like I said, if they process it fast enough they will finish before the next one starts.

Answer (score 1):

Working with large number of files that will fit into system memory, a significant performance improvement can be achieved by using ramdisk, check this out:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/

To create a ramdisk, simply do:

```
# mkfs -q /dev/ram1 8192
# mkdir -p /ramcache
# mount /dev/ram1 /ramcache
```

Comment: next to this, should i copy files to ramdisk?

Comment: I guess you should just copy them to the mount point.. like: `cp files* /ramcache`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) and [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

```
import queue,threading
import glob

q = queue.Queue()
for file in glob.glob(r"MyFolder\data_*.txt"): q.add(file)

class doStuff(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,q):
        self.q = q
        super().__init__()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            file = None
            try: file = q.get_nowait()
            except Queue.Empty: return # end thread
            if file is None: continue
            # if we failed to get a file, forget it
            # DO STUFF WITH YOUR FILE
            #
            # DO STUFF WITH YOUR FILE

for _ in range(10):
    t = doStuff(q)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```